# Photos taken from pictures doesn't show on cropping in cordova camera plugin in android

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Photos taken from pictures do not show on the cropping option using the [camera cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/). But the cropping option appears when I select Image from the gallery or I take picture from the camera.

**plugin**

cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1

**code**

```
 var options = {
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        console.log('succes')
        }, function(err) {
        console.log('succes')
        });
```

I could really need some help to get this problem solved.

Comment: Which version of cordova are you using?

Comment: cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1

Answer (score 2):

you can reference [ngCordove - Camera](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/).

you need dependency injection
 add "ngCordova"，like this.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
```

**camera.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">

        <div class="item item-thumbnail-right item-icon-right" ng-click="toCamera()">
            <img id="myImage" style="margin-right:50px;">
            <h2 class="positive">Camera</h2>
            <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right balanced"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**controllers.js**

```
app.controller('CameraCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

$scope.toCamera = function () {
    var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
        buttons: [
            { text: 'Take a picture' },
            { text: 'Select a picture' }
        ],
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        cancel: function () {
        },
        buttonClicked: function (index) {
            console.log(index);
            if (index == '0') {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                    //take a picture
                    var options = {
                        quality: 100,
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                        allowEdit: true,
                        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                        targetWidth: 1280,
                        targetHeight: 720,
                        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                        correctOrientation: true
                    };
                    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                    }, function (err) {
                        // error
                    });
                }, false);

            } else if (index == '1') {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                    //Select a picture
                    var options = {
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        sourceType: 2,     //set 0 or 2，is system picture
                        quality: 100,
                        allowEdit: true,
                        targetWidth: 1280,
                        targetHeight: 720
                    };

                    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI) {
                        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                        image.src = imageURI;
                    }, function (err) {
                        // error
                    });

                    //$cordovaCamera.cleanup().then(); // only for FILE_URI

                }, false);
            }
            return true;
        }
    })
}});
```

Comment: cropping option appears when I select Image from the gallery or I take picture from the camera but not for the images in pictures

Comment: allowEdit：true Change to false

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify your question?
Is what you want in what happens.

Comment: Like I said if choose any image from gallery it show the cropping option but if choose any image from Photos or File Explorer it is not showing cropping option It directly fecth the image

Comment: I know what you mean. This is the specification limit. Be sure to select the gallery(android native app). Album app is google app,So it is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So is there any way to make it work